# Jquery append() - как отобразить preloader пока работает append()?

Tags: jquery

Я получаю через ajax данные и вставляю их в `div` методом `append()`.
Можно ли как-то поймать когда процесс вставки завершится?
Данных много и получается задержка, а потом появляются `div`.
Хотелось бы вывести прелоадер пока данные вставляются.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку `append` синхронный метод можете попробовать так

```
loading = true; // Тут показываете лоадер

setTimeout(function() { // setTimeout нужен чтобы лоадер успел отобразиться
    $node.append('...'); // Тут вы делаете вставку;
    loading = false; // Тут убираете лоадер
}, 10);
```

Comment: @Alex так напишите смысленный код

Comment: `setTimeout` 10ms совершенно не нужен, чтобы просто показать/скрыть loader, если выполнение синхронное, то и скроется loader после предыдущего действия.

Comment: @Alex Лоадер без таймаута не появится, т.к. показ лоадра, добавление элементов и скрытие лоадера будут в одном фрейме перерисовки происходить.

Comment: Может промисы и/или async/await попробовать?

Comment: @igor 10ms не нужно, отображение будет и при 0.

Comment: @Alex можно и 0, для примера не принципиально.

Comment: я в beforesend запускаю прелоадер, запрос обрабатывается быстро, а вот вставка секунду идет или чуть больше особенно на мобильном заметно, что лоадер скрылся, а данные еще не вставились.

Comment: @SergeyP так скрывайте лоадер после .append(), a не перед ним.

Comment: так я после и вставляю, он сразу срабатывает
            $("#div_blog_content").append(a_msg[1]);
            show_a_loader(0);